# Download R package from github as tar.gz

Tags: r, github

I need to have the tar.gz build version of a package from git.

The git link would look like

`devtools::install_github('repo/package@x.1.0')`

Let's assume it is

`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/lubridate")` but instead of installing I need the actual file so I can install it in in an offline container at some point.

The package I need is not on CRAN, on git only, and I need a specific version of the release, not the latest.

I tried to run a different download.file arguments, no success.

Comment: Perhaps check the releases section, e.g. for lubridate: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/releases has a link for https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/archive/refs/tags/v1.7.10.tar.gz (the tarball for v1.7.10) and you can download the package using `download.file("https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/archive/refs/tags/v1.7.10.tar.gz", destfile = "lubridate.tar.gz")`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Or go to CRAN which has an Archive/ directory for each package, eg [here for lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lubridate/).  In short you are asking the wrong question at github: it's role is not to supply tar.gz (though one can, with effort, in some circumstances when releases are tagged.).  CRAN, on the other hand, works with exactlty the tarballs you are looking for so I would start there.

Comment: Or, more generally, `git clone https://github.com/author/what_i_made.git`, then `R CMD build 'what_I_made`, will create 'what_I_made.tar.gz` (linux), then `R CMD INSTALL what_I_made.tar.gz, to install.

Comment: @jared_mamrot the package I need is not on CRAN, rephrased my initial text

Comment: @Chris what if I need a specific build as of a specific commit? Not the latest one

Comment: Check out the package version you want, and then use `R CMD build` to build the tarball.